# Vba Access error 91

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I try to run this code

```vb
Public Sub Production_UpdateStatus(ByVal lngProductionId As Long, _
                                   ByVal NewProductionStatus As eProductionStatus)    
Dim oDb As DAO.Database
Dim oRst As DAO.Recordset
Dim StrSql As String
Dim strProductionStatus As String

On Error GoTo Err_Infos

GetCurrentProductionStatusString NewProductionStatus, strProductionStatus

Set oDb = CurrentDb

'Mise a jour du staut de production
StrSql = "UPDATE tProduction SET tProduction.Statut= '" & strProductionStatus & "'" _
           & " WHERE (tProduction.IdProduction=" & lngProductionId & ");"
oDb.Execute StrSql

'Fermeture des connexions
oRst.Close
oDb.Close
Set oDb = Nothing
Set oRst = Nothing

Exit_currentSub:
    Exit Sub

Err_Infos:
    MsgBox "Erreur #" & Err.Number & " : " & Err.Description
    Resume Exit_currentSub

End Sub
```

This code work but give me error 91.

> Object variable or With block variable not set

It generate the following SQL query :

```sql
UPDATE tProduction SET tProduction.Statut= 'Nouvelle' WHERE (tProduction.IdProduction=2);
```

When I test direct query, I do not have any error. Could you help me to eliminate this error ?

Thanks

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: remove oRst.Close and Set oRst = Nothing lines. oRst is not initialized and that causes the error, but you don't need oRst for this code.

Comment: Does this error occur at `oDb.Execute StrSql`?  The semicolon is not necessary within VBA, albeit I don't think that's cause here.

Comment: Also, just some advice, use `oDB.execute StrSql, dbFailOnError` where the 2nd parameter will give you an error message if it fails *or as is, fail silently if the query gets bad data*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are closing a recordset object, `oRst`, that was never initialized with `Set`. Because you run an action query you do not need a recordset and it may have lingered from prior code versions.

On that same note, because you are passing literal values to an SQL query, consider parameterizing with [DAO QueryDef parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193967.aspx) that avoids concatenation and quote enclosures:

```vb
Dim oDb As DAO.Database, qdef As DAO.QueryDef
Dim StrSql As String, strProductionStatus As String

GetCurrentProductionStatusString NewProductionStatus, strProductionStatus

Set oDb = CurrentDb

StrSql = "PARAMETERS strProductionStatusParam Text(255), lngProductionIdParam Long;" _
           & " UPDATE tProduction SET tProduction.Statut = [strProductionStatusParam]" _
           & " WHERE (tProduction.IdProduction = [lngProductionIdParam]);"

Set qdef = oDb.CreateQueryDef("", StrSql)

qdef!strProductionStatusParam = strProductionStatus
qdef!lngProductionIdParam = lngProductionId

qdef.Execute dbFailOnError

Set qdef = Nothing
Set oDb = Nothing
```

Comment: You should be able to set the object to nothing, even if the Recordset was not instantiated.  The only caveat there is the type has to be an "object" as you can't set an undeclared (type) to nothing. Albeit the RecordSet should be removed as it's not in use here.

Comment: @JimmySmith the problem isn't with setting it to `Nothing`. The problem is calling instance method `Close` on a null reference. Also try this in the immediate pane: `Set foo = Nothing` and then `?IsObject(foo)`. Outputs `True`, and `foo` is undeclared by definition.

Comment: A-ha.  My misinterpretation there.  Yeah, the .Close line would kill it as it technically has nothing.Close to refer to.  As they never specified where the error was occuring, you're likely right answer here.

Comment: Thanks for the great tips. Your code is working. Thanks for the support, as you should have guess, I am learninq SQL for the moment. With your help I will improve my code faster and better than alone !!

Comment: Great! Glad to help. Please accept solution (tick mark to side) to confirm resolution. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the oRst related code lines. This variable is not initialized and not used.